# Can't access data from named error bag in Laravel view

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-validation

For some reason, I can't access data from an error bag.
I've assigned them to variable in view but I can't display them.

```
@php
    $register_errors = $errors->getBag('register');
    echo($register_errors);
@endphp
@foreach($register_errors as $error)
    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
@endforeach    

echo prints this: {"email":["Email mus\u00ed ma\u0165 spr\u00e1vny form\u00e1t!"],"password":["Heslo mus\u00ed ma\u0165 aspo\u0148 8 charakterov!"],"password_confirmation":["Heslo mus\u00ed ma\u0165 aspo\u0148 8 charakterov!","Hesl\u00e1 sa musia zhodova\u0165!"],"psc":["Pole psc mus\u00ed by\u0165 \u010d\u00edslo."]}
```

foreach displays nothing,
if I try to access them like this: `$register_errors->email / $register_errors->email[0]`. I get no results

I'm sorry for such a newbie(stupid) question, please bear with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel has a special format to display them. Try :

```
{{ $errors->first('email', '<div class="some_name">:message</div>') }}
```

**FOR RENAMED BAG**

If you renamed the bag like :

```
return redirect('register')
        ->withErrors($validator, 'register_errors');
```

You may use :

```
{{ $errors->register_errors->first ('email') }}
```

**TO GET ALL ERROR MESSAGES**

```
@foreach ($errors->all() as $message) {
    <div>{{ $message }}</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Okay, but how do I display them all?

Comment: Loop `$errors->all()` or `$errors->register_errors->all()`